# Does ELSE followed by a nested IF work without braces ?(JAVA)

Tags: java, if-statement, curly-braces

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int j=10;
        if(i>0) 
        if(j>0)
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        else
        System.out.println("else");

    }
}
```

The expected answer is `"else"`,

since `i=0` and hence `ELSE` should be executed.

But the output is `"Hello World"`

The code works fine when I add curly braces to outer `if`.

Comment: Whatever the behavior of this code is or should be, not using braces is asking for trouble. Just use braces, always. And indent your code. Good code is code that is readable by humans, not only by compilers.

Comment: Always use curly braces, a simple rule that will prevent unnecessary headaches

Answer (score 3):

Your code prints NOTHING.

According to documentation:

> > The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an else clause belongs to the innermost if to which it might possibly belong.

while using nested if else without braces, the else block is linked to the nearest if. 
So you code is similar to this:

```
if(i>0) {
    if(j>0){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("else");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without curly braces the `else` belongs to the second (inner) `if` statement, so it's not reached if the first (outer) if statement evaluates to `false`.

It's equivalent to:

```
if(i>0) {
    if(j>0) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    } else {
        System.out.println("else");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will give you the output that you are looking for:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 10;

if(i>0) {
    if(j > 0)
        System.out.println("Hello World");
}
else
    System.out.println("Else");
```

The issue in your original code is that you have this statement:

```
if(i>0)
if(j>0)
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

The system in this situation is evaluating the first if statement which is True, but since it doesn't have braces it isn't being viewed as a nested if statement since you have multiple statements within its' scope (The other if statement and the System.out.println statement) that you want encapsulated within its' scope. So it never evaluates to True. However, the else statement is linked to the if(j<0) statement, so the else statement is also never triggered in this scenario. So you end up with the code not executing. To resolve this I put the second if statement within the first if statements scope with braces. The else statement DOES NOT need to be within braces in this example. Now that the system know that the second if statement is nested within the scope of the first if statement, the else statement is linked to the first if statement and will execute if I is not greater than 0.